# Getstream- How to use the ranking in reaction_counts?

Tags: getstream-io

I had some feeds each feed has different number of likes and comments.how to use the ranking in likes and comments, to sort the feed.

the output should be by using ranking, decreasing in the order of mostlikedposts to leastliked posts.

Answer (score 0):

ranking is enabled with the Growth plan and higher. This blog post gives a good overview of ranking options: https://getstream.io/blog/getting-started-ranked-feeds-getstream-io/

Comment: yeah the above mentioned blog have a good description of ranking, but how do i put the reaction counts(likes and comments ) in ranking

Comment: The team is currently working on tying the reactions API into ranking. Until that's ready, you would need to store the counts as it shows in the blog post.

Comment: @ScottLasica: is this fixed now?

Comment: @KRISHNAKANTHBASKARAN: were u able to get it to work?